# JSON - How to contain dots for the keys in JSONpath

Tags: json, sql-server

For example, we have JSON structure statement:

```
{
"dbo.people": [{
    "p.name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe"
}, {
    "name": "Jane",
    "surname": null,
    "active": true
}]
}
```

When we want to retrieve JSON value "John", the code `JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo, '$.dbo.people[0].p.name')`will not work as expected. So how can we implement the dot in JSONpath?

Answer (score 4):

Use brackets and quotes around the field.

```
JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo, "$['dbo.people'][0]['p.name']")
```

Comment: but this will still cannot solve the dot issue in table name 'dbo.people'?

Comment: @user3651247 I have adjusted my answer to reflect that

Comment: Hi MicFin, I think double quotation are not suggested to be used in SQL Server. It will be unrecognized while using double quotation.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for this situation, which can be written like below:

```
JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo, '$."dbo.dbo.people"[0]."p.name"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes around the field

```
JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo, "$['dbo.people'][0]['p.name']")
```